# Format string into matrix column by column

Tags: python, string, matrix

I'm making this python project and i need to format a given string

```
str = "abcdefghi"
```

In a matrix column by column in order to obtain something like this:

```
M=[[a,d,g],[b,e,h],[c,f,i]]
```

Is there a fast and efficient way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which algorithm are you using? Please add information to your post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a efficient way to do it you could do it with generators or list comprehensions.  Here's a list comprehension:

```
[[i for i in str[i*3:(i*3)+3]] for i in range(len(str) // 3)]
```